How are configuration options for Buildroot generated dynamically?
If I download the fresh buildroot (as of 2024), I can see that when I don't explicitly select the option to build with u-boot, on running make help I will not see anything related to u-boot. On the other hand, if I run menuconfig and select u-boot, I will see the u-boot related configuration options. How does this mechanism work?
P. S.: I see the if/endif part in Config.in located at /boot/uboot. But how does the Makefile include a new dynamic target for this package? It is still not known to me..
P. P. S.: I would ideally like to study how it is done with u-boot so I can do the same thing for my packages.

By "variables" you seem to be referring to configuration options? Apparently you have yet to find/read the README file or the doc/ subdirectory of Buildroot and/or bother looking for the online Buildroot user manual. BTW if you had bothered to actually read the file that I mentioned in your previous Buildroot question, you would already have a piece of the puzzle for this question.

@sawdust Please help, I don't understand :). I remember that you advised me to look into the Config.in file for comments, but I didn't find anything related.
P. S.: I've edited the question to mention configuration options.

Your title asks about the configuration options. Your description asks about the help. Which one of the two do you mean? "How does this mechanism work?" Well it remembers you selected u-boot and then you see the related configuration options. How is that unexpected?

@PeterPointer I searched for a target named 'uboot-menuconfig' and didn't find anything.

which probably means that is being generated dynamically?

Then why not clarify the steps you made in your question? That would help us understand what you're looking for. Just trying to understand it or are you trying to modify something and that doesn't work - or you want to create such a dynamic configuration yourself?

@PeterPointer I've updated the question. I am asking about how it is done in the Makefiles that I can have a dynamic target. I don't see uboot-menuconfig target anywhere in u-boot package sources. Thanks.

Alright, there's a foreach loop inside the help target. I get it now.. Thanks.

You can post an answer to your own question if you've already found it by yourself. Good stuff

When you run make help, Make simply runs the commands for the help target which is defined in the top-level Makefile:
help:
        @echo 'Cleaning:'
        @echo '  clean                  - delete all files created by build'
        @echo '  distclean              - delete all non-source files (including .config)'
        @echo
        @echo 'Build:'
...

In the middle of that very long text is the dynamic part:
        $(foreach p,$(HELP_PACKAGES), \
                @echo $(sep) \
                @echo '$($(p)_NAME):' $(sep) \
                $($(p)_HELP_CMDS)$(sep))

sep is a newline - we can't use an actual newline there because we're within the foreach command.
HELP_PACKAGES is set in the huge inner-generic-package macro in package/pkg-generic.mk. It adds the name of the package to that list if the package is enabled and it defines FOO_HELP_CMDS.
$(p)_NAME and $(p)_HELP_CMDS expand to UBOOT_NAME and UBOOT_HELP_CMDS. UBOOT_NAME is also set by inner-generic-package. UBOOT_HELP_CMDS is set in package/pkg-kconfig.mk
